# Xamarin.Forms How to active a button once the form is filled

Tags: xamarin.forms

```
       <Frame HasShadow="False">
       <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
               <Entry Placeholder="NAME" x:Name="name"></Entry>
               <Entry Placeholder="SURNAME" x:Name="surname"></Entry>
           <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
               <Label  Text="BIRTHDATE" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" ></Label>
               <DatePicker x:Name="birdthdate" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"></DatePicker>
           </StackLayout>
           <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal">
               <Label Text="PICK YEARS" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
               <Picker  Title="YEARS" x:Name="years" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"></Picker>
           </StackLayout>
           <StackLayout Spacing="0">
               <Label Text="Number of docs:"></Label>
               <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" x:name="docs"></Entry>
           </StackLayout>
     
       <Button Text="SAVE"  TextColor="White" Padding="0,-20" BackgroundColor="#07987f" IsEnabled="false" >

               </Button>
       </StackLayout>
       </Frame>
```

My idea is only when user will enter `Name` `Surname` `Birdthdate` `Years` `NumberOfDocs` the button will become enable and can save the data. Any suggestion how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the logic for a simple login with login name + password, where the login button only gets enabled when `LoginName` and `LoginPassword` contains text:

```
private string _loginName;
public string LoginName
{
    get { return _loginName; }
    set 
    { 
        SetProperty(ref _loginName, value);
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsLoginButtonEnabled");
    }
}

private string _loginPassword;
public string LoginPassword
{
    get { return _loginPassword; }
    set 
    { 
        SetProperty(ref _loginPassword, value);
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsLoginButtonEnabled");
    }
}

public bool IsLoginButtonEnabled
{
    get
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LoginName) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(LoginPassword))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Just extend this to your needs and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do that. The easiest way is like the answer from Dennis Schröer. But it doesn't look like you are using MVVM so i have another solution using converters.

Change your button to this:

```
  <Button Padding="0,-20"
              BackgroundColor="#07987f"
              Text="SAVE"
              TextColor="White">
        <Button.IsEnabled>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EnableButtonConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Text"
                     Source="{x:Reference name}" />
            <Binding Path="Text"
                     Source="{x:Reference surname}" />
            <Binding Path="Date"
                     Source="{x:Reference birdthdate}" />
            <Binding Path="SelectedItem"
                     Source="{x:Reference years}" />
          </MultiBinding>
        </Button.IsEnabled>
      </Button>
```

The property `IsEnabled` is bound to all the properties you want it to be dependent on.

The converter does the logic:

```
 public class EnableButtonConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  var name = (string)values[0];
  var surname = (string)values[1];
  //var date = (DateTime)values[2];
  //var year = (string)values[3];

  return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(surname); //&& !year.Equals("YEARS"); //Todo: add a check for the date
}

public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}
}
```

Put the Converter in your pages `ResourceDictionary` and you are good to go.

PS: It's better for performance to use `Grid`-layout instead of multiple `StackLayouts`